# Installing phonegap developer application on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, cordova, simulator

I am trying to install Phonegap developer app on the iOS simulator (ios-sim), but it looks like it's only possible through App Store, which is disabled on the simulator.
What is the easiest way to install it, or what am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to use phonegap serve command on simulator?

Comment: The simulator can not run any apps from the Appstore, since the Appstore apps are ARM based and the simulator is i386. In my experience you just build you Cordova app in xcode and run it from there. This is start the simulator and run you Cordova app. Because all the PhoneGap Developer apps does is open you Cordova app in the iOS wrapper.

Comment: The main purpose of using the developer app is that you can run your apps on real devices without paying for a developer account. If you want to test on the simulator you don't have to pay, you can run your app directly instead of using the developer app. If that didn't convince you, the developer app it's just an open source cordova app, you can get the source code on github, download it and install it in your simulator

Answer (score 0):

The "Phonegap developer app" is only needed if you want to test/debug/run you phonegap applications on your phone. You don't need the "Phonegap developer app" to be installed on an emulator to test it on an emulator.

To run a Phonegap application in the appropriate emulators (assuming you have the [Phonegap CLI](http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/11/13/phonegap-cli-3-6-3/) installed), run the following command(s):

```
phonegap run ios --verbose --stack-trace
phonegap run android --verbose --stack-trace
```

You may need to install the emulators if you haven't got them already)